# Remove Text After xth Word PHP

Tags: php

I have a blog I wrote in PHP, and need to shorten the latest blog post for the front page. I have the latest post in a $variable, and would like to remove all text after the xth word. Between each word I have a space, if that helps. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), where are you stuck?

Comment: You can just google and you will find that substr() wordwrap functions can do this neatly.

Comment: Getting your whole blog post into a variable isn't the best idea... Edit your query, use a substring at the database level itself to get only what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $variable), 0, x));
```

Replacing 'x' with the number of words which you require.

Comment: Thanks you! I've tried various things I've found from Googling, but this is perfect. Thanks!